# Android Never Ending Background Task Methods

Tags: android, android-service, background-process

I am working with Android BackGround Task.ie four task to be exected in background eg location tracking etc. So now to make that work properly i used Foreground Service with one sec timer continuouly which leads to memory leak and Battery Drain.After few research got few ideas about job scheduler,work manager etc.. But I am new to these.So Which one can be used to run non stop task in background.Suggest me Which one is effective.

Comment: Please show us some code you tried.

Comment: make your foreground service a started service and kill it when user closes app - you can save battery that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Firebase Realtime Database**.

There are plenty of tutorials. Refer [this](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268)